# Master Page in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage

I want to find a smooth way to edit/adapt my master page in SharePoint. I already found a way to do it via the Design Manager. But this process is very inconvenient with change it locally and then reupload and "re-insert" the Page into the Master Page-Collection.

Is there any way to edit the masterpage through the SharePoint Designer or does it block this from viewing?

Comment: You can check out your master page and edit it in SharePoint Designer, I see no other way to modifiy it

Comment: @Red thanks for this comment, but the Button for the "Edit in SharePoint Designer" is greyed out. I'm using IE Edge and have SharePoint Designer 2013 installed on my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Modifying a copy of Seattle master.** The Seattle master is the primary master page used for SharePoint 2013. Using it as is will give you a functional site with the SharePoint layout and interface. Modifying this master allows for limited branding; you can, for instance, change the header of your pages.

- Open **SharePoint Designer** and click on **Master Pages**, located in the Navigation pane. You should see few options for master pages like *Seattle.master*, *Oslo.master*, *default.master*, etc.
- **Right click** on Seattle.master. Now you want to paste a copy of the master into the Master Page Gallery.
- Now you have **Seattle_copy(1).master**. Click on this to see summary information in the gallery.
- Next, click **Edit File**. You will find this option in the ribbon commands. Here, you can customize your page’s **tags, styles, content regions, and scripts**. You can see what your edits look like as you make them, which is helpful. You will also work with content placeholder controls (this represents content that can be displayed or hidden on the content pages).
- To change the style of the master page, click on **Site Settings**, then **Customization**, and finally Change **site theme**. This allows you to apply a predesigned theme. You can also create your own themes and add them to the page yourself. This option allows you to achieve a look that is more reflective of your brand.
- You can also manage styles or create custom cascading style; to do this, click on **Style** and **Manage Styles**.
- Make your new page the primary master page for your site by finding **Site Objects** in the Navigation pane. Choose **Master Pages**. Right click on the page you’ve created to make it the master and select **Set as Default Master Page**.
- **Celebrate your hard work** and bask in the adoration of your coworkers. This may not really happen, but you can take a minute to pat yourself on the back.

Check below video as it shows how to add footer to SharePoint Master Page.

[Customize A SharePoint 2013 Master Page](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7GM6Fnz_H4)